# How to change the build directory in SvelteKit?

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

In SvelteKit, I can't figure out a way to change the path of the actual build directory (not the app or the generated directory) via configuration. I've tried changing it in Vite configuration (1) but I get the message (2).

1.

```js
// vite.config.ts
import { sveltekit } from "@sveltejs/kit/vite"
import { defineConfig } from "vite"

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [ sveltekit() ],
    build: { outDir: "builds" }
})
```

2. 

```bash
The following Vite config options will be overridden by SvelteKit:
  - build.outDir
```

For context, I'm making a mono-repo for a cross-platform app with the Vite generated SvelteKit build as a basis for the native platform apps.

Comment: Not sure if this help, you can define your own build route when using sveltekit `adapter-static` https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help from Patrick of the Svelte Discord I learned the correct configuration is the `pages` key in the adapter options ([read](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/adapter-static#options-pages).)

```js
// svelte.config.js
import adapter from "@sveltejs/adapter-static"
import { vitePreprocess } from "@sveltejs/kit/vite"

/** @type {import("@sveltejs/kit").Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/integrations#preprocessors
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: vitePreprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter({ pages: "builds" })
    }
}

export default config
```